# Installed but still getting RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pynacl

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
```

I've been working on a discord bot for practicing purposes and I've been stuck on getting it to join a voice channel. I have PyNaCl installed and I've swapped between 1.3.0 and 1.4.0 with pip to see if it'd make a difference and nothing. I made sure libsodium was installed thinking that would solve the issue but I'm still getting the same errors whenever I try to make the bot join a voice channel.

I'm willing to try out any other troubleshooting methods and fixes but I've scoured stackoverflow with no results so far.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import youtube_dl
from discord import channel


try:
    import nacl.secret
    has_nacl = True
except ImportError:
    has_nacl = False
```

These are the imports to my work, I tried just using just 'import.nacl' with no results either.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might have multiple Python installations installed.

Comment: @TinNguyen I reinstalled all versions of python and it did resolve the issue. It did turn out I had 3.6 as well as 3.7 installed on my PC. Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your time!